# Angular - Wait for data from service before executing next steps

Tags: angular

How can I wait for my `user` object to be fully loaded from the sharedService before executing the next lines of code? The extent of how I know to implement this is only with `setTimeout()`

```
const user = this.sharedService.GetLoggedUser;

let name = user.firstName;
let email = user.email;
let phone = user.phoneNumber;
```

Comment: What is `this.sharedService.GetLoggedUser`? An Observable? A Promise? If it is an observable, you need to subscribe to it. If it is a promise, you need the `.then()` with callback.

Answer (score 1):

If GetLoggedUser is an API call you should consider doing following

```
let name;
let email;
let phone;       

this.sharedService.GetLoggedUser().subscribe(user => {
          this.name = user.firstName;
          this.email = user.email;
          this.phone = user.phoneNumber; 
});
```

your get logged user method should look similar to this

```
getUserUrl = 'http://host/user';

GetLoggedUser() {
  // pass parameters accordingly
  return this.http.get<User>(this.getUserUrl);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an API request and I don't have access to the subscribe method.